# How to convert years to days (in the past)?

Tags: linux, bash, command

I want convert years to days (in the past) with a Linux command. For example:

1. The user give number: 10 years ago
2. The program should calculate the sum of the days in 10 years ago (e.x: 10*12*31 (years/month/days) --> 3720 days).
3. The program sum it with current days from begin this year (ex: 3720 + 223) and return it.

Comment: Why should 10 years equal 3720 days? Which universe do you run Linux on?

Comment: Only Earthlings use 365 days in a year.

Comment: it's just example , please help if you can! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current time in seconds since 1970/01/01 (The Unix 'day 1'):

```
dnow=$(date +"%s")
```

The time exactly 10 years ago:

```
dthen=$(date -d '-10 years' +"%s")
```

Calculate today's day in the year:

```
dity=$(date +"%j")
```

Then just subtract one from the other, divide by the number of seconds in a day, and add today's day-in-the-year:

```
timespan=$(( (dnow - dthen) / (24*60*60) + dity ))
```

You should set `$dnow` after `$dthen`, to avoid an off-by-one error.

I'm not sure why anyone would want to do this, so if I've misinterpreted your question, please come back to us.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the day of the year, 10 years from now:

```
date -d '+10 years' +"%j"
```